# What exactly is the phase of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology, definition

I've heard the term "phase" several times (e.g. in the context of waves), not just in the context of complex numbers (which are often mentioned e.g. in the context of quantum computing), but, in this post, I would like to know the **definition of a phase of a complex number**. So, what is it?

Here are a few sub-questions to help you answer
(more thoroughly) the main question above (so you don't have to answer all these sub-questions, but, if you answer them, the main question will probably be answered more satisfactorily).

- Why is it called a "phase"?
- Why do we care about phases of complex numbers?
- Can a complex number have different phases and still be considered the same complex number?
- What are examples of applications of this property of a complex number?

Comment: Let me compose a hypothetical example in the next comment. The main issue (as I see it) is that currently the post looks exactly the same as a "gimme teh codez" question by someone who puts no effort in their homework or no effort in even reading their textbook.

Comment: Here is a variation of your question post.
**Title:** (the same) "What exactly is the phase of a complex number?"
**Body:** "I've encountered the term "phase" under various contexts. and I'd like to know exactly (with some formatting to highlight) _what is the definition of a phase of a complex number_.  (new paragraph) Why is it called a "phase"?  In engineering or physics, ... `insert a couple of sentences for that context`, therefore the notion of phase is nice and useful. However, I don't see the point of such a concept for the complex numbers. Can someone provide some examples?"

Comment: My point is that you should "compose" the question instead of just listing consecutive short question marks. Again, like I said, this is an edge case for me.

Comment: Many users of this site don't want to be bothered with formality, and that's fine. However, in this case where the question doesn't stem from a person currently needing help, formality becomes very important. If you want the post to be a useful entry in the database, then efforts should be made in having the question post "looks nice".

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin This is the third Google result for "complex phase" for me. I can't say I understand your argument here. Please forgive me for finding this post useful

Comment: @AustinAdams I'm glad you find it useful, and it's a good thing you actually voiced your support for the OP. I stand corrected. As a long time user of this site, presumably you are aware of the age-old fracture within the community regarding what kind of "cultural norms" we should strive for. In fact, this conflict is a big part of the reasons that I haven't used StackExchange for the past 20 months. It was exactly due to not really being comfortable with the vote that I left those comments. Anyway, if this conversation is to be continued it should be in the meta site or a chat room.

Comment: I'm sorry, nbro, but I have issues with feigned questions, just so a non-asker can show and tell.  I'm not the only such user on this site that feels that way.  I make exceptions for phenomenal question/answer submissions, but your duo doesn't meet that bar.  Just because you *can* ask and answer, doesn't mean you should. In general, if it looks like show and tell, and walks like a "show and tell"...

Comment: @amWhy Ok, no problem.

Comment: @amWhy More reasons why I have a dislike for this stack site particularly. It is too critical of the users and stringent on the submission criteria. heavily moderated, unnecessarily so. It is not an encouraging or welcoming place, in general. At least a stack post is not meant to be an academic paper!

Answer (score 11):

A complex number can be represented in a "rectangular" or "polar" forms.

The rectangular form of a complex number $z$ is composed of a real part and the imaginary part: $z = a + bi$, where $a$ is the real part and $b$ is the imaginary part, and $i$ is the imaginary unity, $\sqrt{-1}$. We can visualise such number in a 2-dimensional plane , called the "complex plane", as follows:

[image]

where "Im" refers to the "imaginary" axis and "Re" to the real axis. Why is it called "rectangular form"? Because of the rectangle we can see in the picture above.

In the polar representation, rather than specifying the coordinates (of the complex plane) $a$ and $b$ of the complex number, we specify the angle (counterclockwise sense) between the real axis ("Re") and the vector representing the complex number, and the length of such vector. Formally, the polar representation of a complex number $z$ is $z=r(\cos \varphi +i\sin \varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is the angle between the real axis and the vector (in blue in the figures) and $r$ is the length (or magnitude or module) of such vector. We similarly visualise such polar representation as follows

[image]

where $y=b$ and $x=a$ (that is, we just changed letters). Why is it called "polar form"? Because the angle $\varphi$ is also often called the "polar angle".

Mathematically, the complex number $z=r(\cos \varphi +i\sin \varphi)$ is equivalent to $z=re^{i\varphi}$, because of the [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), which is $e^{i \varphi}=\cos \varphi + i \sin \varphi$, which holds for any real number $\varphi$.

[image]

In our case, the real number $\varphi$ is the angle.

In this context, we often call the **phase** either the term $e^{i\varphi}$ or simply the angle $\varphi$. Note that the angle $\varphi$ completely determines $e^{i\varphi}$, that is, given $\varphi$, we can easily retrieve $e^{i\varphi}$ (without any other information) by simply replacing this angle in the Euler's identity.

> Can a complex number have different phases and still be considered the same complex number?

Suppose that we have complex numbers $z_1 = re^{i2\pi}$ (a complex number of length $r$ which lies on the real axis and points to the right) and $z_2 = re^{i4\pi}$. Clearly, $z_1 = z_2$, but they have different "phases": $z_1$ has phase $e^{i2\pi}$ (or $2\pi$), whereas $z_2$ has phase $e^{i4\pi}$ (or $4\pi$). Hence, $z_1$ and $z_2$, even though they have different phases, they represent the exact same complex number. Hence, in general, two polar representations with different phases can represent the same complex number.

> Why is $\varphi$ (or $e^{i\varphi}$) called a "phase"?

Because it refers to the angle around the origin of the complex plane.

> What are examples of applications of this property of a complex number?

For example, [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), which represents the discrete Fourier transform (DFT), is a special matrix. If we look at the Wikipedia article on the DFT matrix, we can see the entries of such vector are complex numbers with different phases.

(Images in this answer are screenshots of the images of Wikipedia articles).